# Objective-C: How to remove notification by selector?

Tags: objective-c, notifications

When setting up notification, you can set different selector to react to it. But there seems no way to remove notification by selector.  For example:

```
// e.g. React to background notification by calling method 1
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method1:) name:notification object:nil];


// e.g. React to background notification by calling method 2    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method2:) name:notification object:nil];
```

Now when the notification fires, both methods will react to it.
How do I remove notification selectively (e.g. remove notification handler method1)?

Comment: It doesn't look like you can, but there is no reason to register two methods to receive the same notification on the same class in the first place.

Comment: There is reason in my case because the two operations are distinctly different.

Comment: Call `method2` from `method1` under those conditions.  You need to remember those conditions anyway in order to correctly remove the notification.

Comment: give a try by     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:<#notificationName#> object:nil]

Comment: I don't want to mix code for method1 and method2 into the same method with if-cases.  That breaks the encapsulation.

Comment: @Johnykutty That won't work - it's still tied to a particular observer.

Comment: I think I may just use proxy objects to proxy the two calls instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it, but I don't think you will like it.

Use `-addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` instead.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

// e.g. React to background notification by calling method 1
self.method1Observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:notification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    [weakSelf method1:note];
}];

// e.g. React to background notification by calling method 2    
self.method2Observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:notification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    [weakSelf method2:note];
}];
```

Then later on:

```
// Remove method 1 observer while keeping method 2 observer.
if (self.method1Observer != nil) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.method1Observer];
    self.method1Observer = nil;
}
```

---

**Update:** I forgot to `nil` check `self.method1Observer` before passing it to `-removeObserver:`.

Comment: This seems like a great way.  Why don't you think I will like it?

Comment: Because of the added complexities. It requires creating two new properties which only serve as place holders for `-removeObserver:`. You also must be careful with retain cycles (hence the `weakSelf` variable). In addition, there is a bit of indirection: the target/action is not called directly, but a block is called which then calls your target action. None of this is really clean design.

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove that notification when it will not necessary in that class. So simply use below code for remove already added Notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"Notification" object:nil];
```